# I can't build android app with react-native-image-crop-picker

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I want to add multiple image upload feature so I installed react-native-image-crop-picker library to my project and i made the steps in readme which is here [README](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/blob/master/README.md)

But when i try to build project

`react-native run-android`

i get error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2-native.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/C:/Users/mmtbo/.m2/repository/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.2-native/ucrop-2.2.2-native.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/mmtbo/.m2/repository/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.2-native/ucrop-2.2.2-native.jar
       - file:/C:/Users/mmtbo/workspace/imagePickertest/node_modules/react-native/android/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.2-native/ucrop-2.2.2-native.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/mmtbo/workspace/imagePickertest/node_modules/react-native/android/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.2-native/ucrop-2.2.2-native.jar
       - file:/C:/Users/mmtbo/workspace/imagePickertest/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.2-native/ucrop-2.2.2-native.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/mmtbo/workspace/imagePickertest/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.2-native/ucrop-2.2.2-native.jar
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.2-native/ucrop-2.2.2-native.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.2-native/ucrop-2.2.2-native.jar
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.2-native/ucrop-2.2.2-native.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.2-native/ucrop-2.2.2-native.jar
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-image-crop-picker
```

i couldn't find much thing about this error.

this is from android/build.gradle

```
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android" }

        // ADD THIS
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

        // ADD THIS
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.imagepickertest"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
```

Comment: Change library version to 2.2.3/ update the module

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to follow the `Post-Install` steps.

You have to add jitpack.io to repositories.

Here is the link: https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker#android-1

Comment: ı made ```post-install``` steps. Should I add anything else other than them

Comment: That should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You shold very importantly add the following line in android/build.gradle file

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

So your android/build.gradle file should look like below

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        .......                 //if there are any other modules
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Also see the post steps in the documentation and follow the steps

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-crop-picker#android-1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and probably it was an issue with the latest version `0.35.0`.

Solved it by downgrading to version `0.34.1`.

**Edit:**
I've found the real solution for the problem.

You should upgrade you gradle: `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1`

[Source](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/issues/1406#issuecomment-693344146)

Answer (score 0):

if anyone in future still have problem for build app  after installing image-picker just turn on your VPN

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).